# How to customize filename in browsers builtin PDF viewer for base64 pdfs

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, pdf.js, pdfobject

I'm embedding PDFs from a base64 string like this:

```js
var pdfData = 'data:application/pdf;filename=MY_CUSTOM_FILENAME.pdf;base64,' +
  'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
  'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
  'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
  'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
  'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
  'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
  'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
  'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
  'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
  'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
  'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
  'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
  'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G';

function loadPdf() {
  var pdf= document.querySelector('.pdf')

  var pobj = document.createElement('object')
  pobj.className= "pdf_object"
  pobj.setAttribute('data', pdfData)
  pobj.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf')

  pdf.appendChild(pobj)
}
```

```css
.pdf_object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="loadPdf();">
    CLICK TO LOAD BELOW THE PDF
  </button>
</div>
<div class="pdf"></div>
```

This works both on Firefox and Chrome.

My problem is I cannot customize the filename for the pdf download actions. Notice that I'm using the `filename`parameter (`'data:application/pdf;filename=MY_CUSTOM_FILENAME.pdf;...`), but it's ignored.

On Firefox, I get this warning (related code is [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/ui_utils.js)):

> "getPDFFileNameFromURL: ignoring "data:" URL for performance reasons."

And the pdf's filename is the default `document.pdf`.

On Chrome, I get no warning, but filename sticks to the default `download.pdf`.

So, how can I customize the filename? Is that possible?

I tried these ways, unsuccessfully:

- Checked [PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject), which is a library doing basically what I'm doing in this post (discovered it while writing this!), but they seem to not allow any customization on the filename.
- I tried to load pdf on an `<iframe>`, and then manipulating its content. But I get (at least in Firefox) a Cross Origin error
- It seems that Mozilla's PDF viewer ([PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)) also checks the `Content-Disposition` header for guessing out the pdf's filename. Could be possible to somehow simulate an HTTP request (always locally in the browser, as I work with base64 strings) and use it to load the pdf viewer?

I know the solution can be to directly use [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), but if possible I would love to avoid this dependency (and also the coding, cause it's not so straightforward to implement it). At the end, I just want to customize filename!

Thanks!

---

EDIT: The code snippet below does not work on Chrome (Failed to load 'data:application/pdf;filename=MY_CUSTOM_FILENAME.pdf;base64,....' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.), but it works if you open a plan .html file.

---

EDIT 2: I found a solution but it just works on Firefox.

We will convert our `base64` string to a `Blob` [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/13045101), convert this `Blob` to Url and add a `filename` parameter to this url (using '#' [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581618/13045101)).

So, the `loadPdf()` function is this:

```js
function loadPdf() {
  fetch(pdfData)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      try {
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        // This line makes Chrome crash, we have to remove it there
        // But it works on Firefox
        blobUrl+= '#filename=MY_CUSTOM_FILENAME.pdf'

        var pdf= document.querySelector('.pdf')
        var pobj = document.createElement('object')
        pobj.className= "pdf_object"
        pobj.setAttribute('data', blobUrl)
        pobj.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf')

        pdf.appendChild(pobj)
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
  })
}
```

When downloading from Firefox's Pdf viewer, we'll successfully see MY_CUSTOM_FILENAME.pdf.

But on Chrome we will see the Blob url's hash. And:

- [it seems impossible to change that hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41947861/13045101)
- even if I use an `<iframe>` (instead of an `<object>`) to load my inline pdf, Chrome will make use of an `<embed>`. So, there's no way to "hack" it.

Any other tip from this perspective?

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to get this working in Chrome?

Comment: Hi, I ended up directly using PDFjs and customizing it. I save the filename in sessionStorage, and then PDFjs viewer will take that value from sessionStorage.
So, sadly, no solution still for my problem